# How to insert Time with AM/PM to MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert Time in MySQL database. In database I have two separate Fields for Date(date type) and Time(Time type). To insert a record I tried like below in my PHP. But Time only inserted(10:00:00). not AM/PM inserted. How to insert Time with AM/PM in PHP.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Http(mobile, imei, time,date) VALUES ('1232456785', '123369584895544', TIME_FORMAT( '10:00:00', '%h:%i:%s %p' ),'2011/09/13')");
```

Comment: How about using mysql DATETIME column type which combines date + time into a single field and uses a 24 hour clock ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it. Here are formats for TIME type: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html

Comment: So it is not possible to store Time with AM/PM in Time type Field of MySQL Database.Only way is using 24 hour Time format?

Comment: Thank You...Can i use Varchar for time Field.(To use AM/PM with Time)...is it good way?...

Comment: I'm not so sure that it's good way. Why you don't want convert time direct in your programm?